# Rails design of an online newspaper -- controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have started a Ruby on Rails 3 project to make an online version of newspaper. The front page has the news headlines, sports headlines and life headlines. It has all the headlines for the different sections of the site.

All the stories are stored in one table and photos in another table. It is a very simple set up. I am trying be DRY but I can't seem to avoid it. On the index action page I have to look up sports stories and on the sports action page I have to look up sports.

My question is should I make a different controller for every category? Or have a main controller with categories as actions? ( which is what I am doing now? )

Comment: In essence, what you are looking to create is a Content Management System (CMS), you may benefit from looking at some existing CMS applications to see how they approach data modeling, routing, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a single Story controller that takes a querystring to determine the category.  In other words, if you go to

/stories/

you get the front page, which lists all (or a portion of all) stories.  If you want sports you go to

/stories/?category=sports

and the Story controller filters the list of stories (and presumably alters the view headings, etc.) based on the querystring.